# gnuplot drawing multiple plots in same chart

Tags: gnuplot

I'm trying to follow the guide to plotting financial data on gnuplot found here:

http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/finance.html

I generated some data and tried plotting with the following script:

```
  1 set datafile separator ","
  2 set object 1 rectangle from screen 0,0 to screen 1,1 fillcolor rgb"#cccccc" behind
  3 
  4 set xdata time
  5 set timefmt "%Y-%M-%dT%H:%M:%S"
  6 set format x "%d-%H"
  7 
  8 set ylabel "Price"
  9 set xlabel 'Time'
 10 
 11 set style line 100 lt 1 lc rgb "grey" lw 0.5
 12 set style line 101 lt 1 lc rgb "orange" lw 1
 13 
 14 set grid ls 100
 15 set key off
 16 
 17 plot "lastrun.dat" using 1:2 with lines, '' using 1:3 with lines ls 101, '' using 1:4 with lines ls 101
```

however the resulting graph seems to not stich together the data correctly, so instead of one chart, i have three in the same space.

[image]

i'm sure i'm making a simple error but I've been stumped about what that is.

Comment: Please don't show line numbers and please show a few lines of example data. Ok, now I see, for the month it should read `%m` not `%M`, i.e. `set timefmt "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `help time_specifiers`:

> ```
> %d day of the month, 01–31 
> %H hour, 00–23 (always two digits) 
> %m month, 01–12 
> %M minute, 0–60 
> %S second, integer 0–60 on output, (double) on input 
> %Y year, 4-digit
> ```